# Maximum of (arr[i] - arr[j]) where i < j

Tags: algorithm

This is the solution I came up with which has O(n^2) time complexity

```
        int x= 0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            for (int j = i+1; j < Dif.length; j++){
               if (x < (Dif[i] - Dif[j])) {
                    x = Dif[i] - Dif[j];
                }
            }
```

Comment: Why do you think this is `O(n^2)`?

Comment: Because there is two for loops one inside the other which last till the size of the array which is n both so n*n=n^2

Comment: It would be `n * n` if internal loop started at `0`, but the internal loop  starts at `i+1` instead. White this out in terms of number of operations for array of length, say, 4, and see for yourself.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov It is still *O(n^2)*.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Ya I have to make it to O(n log n) which seems to be difficult I am open to any suggestions

Comment: @NicoSchertler, how? For `n = 4` it'll do 6 comparisons in total, for `n=5` it'll do 10. That's doesn't look like `an^2 + bn` to me, because `b` also then seems to depend on `n`. What am I missing?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Yes, exactly. The number of comparisons is: `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + ... + (n-1)`. This is `n^2/2 - n/2`.

Comment: @NicoSchertler, ah. This is what lack of actual CS education does to me, it seems. You're right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's take a closer look at the expression

```
max(arr[i] - arr[j])  for i < j
```

Let's assume our `j` is fixed. Then, the expression simplifies to

```
[max(arr[i]) for i < j] - arr[j]
```

And this immediately gives us an algorithm where we can incrementally calculate the maximum of the subsequence up to `j-1`:

```
max = arr[0] //the maximum element of the subarray
maxDiff = -infinity //the maximum difference seen so far
for j from 1 to n-1
    diff = max - arr[j]
    //check if we found a better difference
    if diff > maxDiff
        maxDiff = diff
    //update the maximum element
    if arr[j] > max
        max = arr[j]
return maxDiff
```

This is linear in the number of elements.

Comment: Brilliant! What about if we remove the condition (i<j)? @Nico Schertler

Comment: @ManojBanik Then it is simply the maximum array element minus the minimum array element. Both can be found in linear time as well.